# JFile Chooser Query

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How to display JFile-Chooser at the Center of the screen. The conventional method of using ToolKit is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Javadoc for the method [JFileChooser#showDialog(Component parent, String approveButtonText) throws HeadlessException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String%29), it says:

> The parent argument determines two
>   things: the frame on which the open
>   dialog depends and the component whose
>   position the look and feel should
>   consider when placing the dialog. If
>   the parent is a Frame object (such as
>   a JFrame) then the dialog depends on
>   the frame and the look and feel
>   positions the dialog relative to the
>   frame (for example, centered over the
>   frame). If the parent is a component,
>   then the dialog depends on the frame
>   containing the component, and is
>   positioned relative to the component
>   (for example, centered over the
>   component). **If the parent is null**,
>   then the dialog depends on no visible
>   window, and it's placed in a
>   look-and-feel-dependent position such
>   as **the center of the screen**.